# Bitbucket pipeline with Angular 5 project (OVH Public Cloud)

Tags: angular, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, ovh, autodeploy

I have a Public Cloud in [OVH](https://www.ovh.pt/public-cloud/instances/) and I need to automate deploy process, but I'm having difficulties to finding a good documentation or tutorial.

Need to make auto deploy using Bitbucket pipeline and OVH Public Cloud (using SSH).
I don't know if using FTP or another way to pass the Angular 5 build files to Cloud.

Currently I using GitLab repository, but I have difficulties too (but I migrating to Bitbucket now).

I can get help for this question?